# getting RethinkDB: RqlDriverError: Handshake timedout

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I am using RethinkDB as my DB backend with ember.js but when i am trying to run it i am getting

```
myproject\server\config\db.js:12
        throw error;
        ^
 RqlDriverError: Handshake timedout
```

on 12 line of my `db.js` file

Here is my db.js file

```
'use strict';

var Bluebird = require('bluebird');
var r = require('rethinkdb');
var config = require('config');

module.exports = function (cb) {
  return new Bluebird(function (resolve, reject) {
    r.connect(config.db, function(error, conn) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
        throw error;
      }

      conn.use('fitforms');
      resolve(conn);

      if (cb) {
        cb(conn);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Here is my default.json5 where i am configuring my db address

```
{
  baseUrl: 'localhost:4211',

  db: {
    host: '162.273.196.43',
    port: 8080
  },

  email: {
    from: 'someemail.com',
    user: 'efegegegegegdgd',
    pass: '6Dhrdhfhfhfh',
  },

  stripe: {
    secret: 'sfgsgdgdgdgddgdgdgFFddd'
  }
}
```

Not sure what went wrong.

Comment: Is it possible that the server and driver versions don't match?

Comment: that might i will check that..